# If Three Instances, Delete Line

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a list with four lines:

file1.txt

```
A_1_2 
A_2_3
A_3_4
B_1_2
B_2_3
B_3_4
```

I then found all possible combinations up to 4 per line, with an example being:

file2.txt

```
A_1_2 A_2_3 A_3_4 A_3_4
A_1_2 A_2_3 B_1_2 B_2_3
```

What I would like to do is if there are 3 instances containing `A` then remove the line:

output.txt

```
A_1_2 A_2_3 B_1_2 B_2_3
```

How would I do this? I know that there are commands that use two unique strings, but those do not work for me. Please let me know how to make the question better if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: otherwise with grep `grep -Ev '(\<A.*){3}' file2.txt`

Answer (score 1):

`awk` provides a simple way to check if you have three of more fields beginning with `'A'`. You can simply loop over each of the four fields in each line of `file2.txt` and use `substr()` to check the first character of each field. Keep a counter each time `"A"` is encountered, and if your counter reaches `3` skip the line, e.g.

```
awk '{n=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(substr($i,1,1)=="A" && ++n==3) next }1' file2.txt
```

With your `file2.txt` as the input file, you receive the output:

```
A_1_2 A_2_3 B_1_2 B_2_3
```

You can read about the `substr()` function in detail in the [GNU Awk - String Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) section. The `1` at the end of the command is just shorthand for the default action `print` to print those lines not skipped. Let me know if you have further questions, or if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

In plain `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    [[ \ $line =~ \ A.*\ A.*\ A ]] || printf "%s\n" "$line"
done < file2.txt
```

Or, using `grep`:

```
 grep -Ev '(^| )A.* A.* A' file2.txt
```